# What will be the effect of torque and wheel diameter on the stability of a robot?

Tags: design, stability

I'm building a self balancing robot and would like to know how the wheel diameter and the torque provided by DC motors, would affect the overall stability and response of the robot. The balancing bot is based on the principle of an inverted pendulum.